# Determinant and restriction of scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, fields, determinants

Let $E/F$ be a finite separable extension of fields, and $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $E$. Let $T\in\operatorname{End}_EV$ be a linear operator on $V$, and let $\det(T)$ be its determinant. Now one can view $T$ as an  $F$-linear operator on $V$ by viewing $V$ as an $F$-vector space. Let $\det_F(T)$ be the determinant of $T$ viewed as an $F$-linear operator. Is it true that

$\det_F(T)=N_{E/F}(\det(T))$

where $N_{E/F}$ is the norm from $E$ to $F$?

If so, is there any reference or simple proof?

Comment: As with many things, this follows from Theorem 1 in [John R. Silvester, *Determinants of Block Matrices*, The Mathematical Gazette, Vol. 84, No. 501 (Nov., 2000), pp. 460--467](https://web.archive.org/web/20140505161153/http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jrs/gazette/blocks.pdf). In fact, the matrix that represents $T$ as an $F$-linear operator on $V$ is a block matrix, whose blocks are elements of $F$ written as square matrices over $E$; clearly these blocks commute. Separability of $E/F$ is unnecessary.

Comment: This is a special case of Bourbaki, _Algèbre_ III.9.4 Proposition 6.

Comment: @darijgrinberg it is not true that these blocks commute. For instance if $A+iB$ is a complex $n\times n$ matrix, then the matrix representing it over $\mathbb{R}$ is the $2\times 2$ block matrix with blocks $A ,-B ,B ,A$, but $A,B$ don't commute. I don't see how theorem 1 implies the original question.

Comment: @Espace'etale: You want to represent it as an $n\times n$ block matrix made out of commuting $2 \times 2$-blocks, not as a $2\times 2$ block matrix made out of commuting $n \times n$-blocks. Each $2 \times 2$-block will have the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$ for two real numbers $a$ and $b$; but all such blocks commute.

Comment: Very good, wonderful! Infact the blocks will in general be members of an embedding of $E$ inside the ring of matrices over $E$ of size  $[E:F]$, right?